# Ionic 5 App not Refreshing HomeScreen after Login

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, cross-platform, ionic5

I have an Ionic App that was created with Ionic 3 and recently updated to Ionic 5 (Angular 8).
The App is running in Chrome Browser (with `ionic serve`) without any problems, and everything is working the way it should.

For almost 2 weeks I am trying to make a version running for iOS.
I have the latest XCode 12 installed and tried to create a build with `ionic cordova build ios --prod`. After the build is finished I open the Project-File in xCode and try to test it on my iPhone.
The Login-Screen appears and the user can authenticate by clicking a login button. This opens a `InAppBrowser` where the user can be authenticated. After a successful authentication the `InAppBrowser` closes and a logged-in `flag` is set to `true`.

Usually, this should allow to show some tiles content within the home screen.
For some reason the page is not refreshed and it does not show the tiles.
The first `Rest-request` seems to be working fine and I can see after I was debugging the home-page that the user-information is received successfully.
In xCode I can see some error messages:

```
2021-03-11 10:37:06.003856+0100 EPDM[795:40716] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO

2021-03-11 10:37:06.370470+0100 EPDM[795:40716] [ProcessSwapping] 0x108c981a8 - ProvisionalPageProxy::didFailProvisionalLoadForFrame: pageProxyID=13 webPageID=23, frameID=3, navigationID=3

2021-03-11 10:37:06.370687+0100 EPDM[795:40716] [Process] 0x102079218 - [pageProxyID=13, webPageID=18, PID=804] WebPageProxy::didFailProvisionalLoadForFrame: frameID = 3, domain = NSURLErrorDomain, code = -1004

2021-03-11 10:37:06.371059+0100 EPDM[795:40716] webView:didFailProvisionalNavigation - -1004: Could not connect to the server.

2021-03-11 10:37:15.669294+0100 EPDM[795:40716] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service
```

My question is what might be causing this error?
Thank you in advance for your answers.

```
"config": {
    "ionic_webpack": "./config/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "fix": "tslint --c tslint.json 'src/**/*.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.27",
    "@angular/forms": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/http": "7.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "8.2.14",
    "@ionic-native-mocks/http": "^2.0.12",
    "@ionic-native/abbyy-rtr": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic-native/http": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic-native/ionic-webview": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.5.4",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "2.3.3",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^9.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-android": "^6.4.0",
    "cordova-browser": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-ios": "6.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-3dtouch": "1.3.5",
    "cordova-plugin-abbyy-rtr-sdk": "^1.0.4",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ionicons": "5.4.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "ngx-progressbar": "^2.1.1",
    "npm": "^6.14.8",
    "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "^8.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.3",
    "svg-pan-zoom": "^3.6.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "tslint-fix": "^0.1.3",
    "zone.js": "0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ahovakimyan/cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix": "git+https://github.com/AraHovakimyan/cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix.git",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.803.19",
    "@angular-devkit/build-webpack": "0.803.19",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "8.2.2",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "8.2.2",
    "@angular/cli": "8.3.29",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.2.14",
    "@babel/compat-data": "7.8.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.45",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^3.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-cookies": "0.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-deeplinks": "^1.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.7",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-keychain-touch-id": "^3.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix": "^0.1.0",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^5.1.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "^8.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^3.0.3",
    "ts-node": "^3.0.2",
    "typescript": "3.5.1",
    "ws": "3.3.2"
  },
  "description": "An EpdmMobileApps project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-keychain-touch-id": {},
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-deeplinks": {},
      "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-cookies": {},
      "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": {
        "OKHTTP_VERSION": "3.10.0"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did try to pin-point the code that was causing this problem.
I was commenting out some steps during the login that might cause problems.

After commenting out the call of the InAppBrowser, i did not see any more errors.
I realized, that the redirect that i received from the backend caused an  loaderror -event within the InAppBrowser. This is what created the
'''
webView:didFailProvisionalNavigation - -1004: Could not connect to the server.
'''
error message.
My other code was called from within this InAppBrowser loaderror Event, and i guess that the WebView is not able to handle this after an error occurred.